# Masking the password field in Java 1.4

Tags: java, user-input, java1.4

I have working code to mask User Input for Java 1.6 using Console.readPassword().

But there is a legacy system which supports Java 1.4 only.Obviously this code will not work there as Console is included in Java 6.

Is there a way we can mask password on User Input in Java 1.4 ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you have to use Java 1.4? What are you using to capture user input in 1.4, System.in? If so, there's not much you can do to hide it if your program must run in a command window

Comment: It a system live in production. They will not allow installing another Java version there.Yes, my initial attempt in 1.4 is using System.in and a Buffered Reader. Yeah, looked up a lot online , no solution in sight :( .But,is it possible that I can package the jdk 1.6 and just point to java.exe without actually installing Java 1.6 on that system?

Comment: Try https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldapsdk/docs/javadoc/com/unboundid/util/PasswordReader.html or you can implement their idea yourself